# Smple way to get min & max

Tags: code-golf, string, math

You will take a set of input numbers, and output the minimum and maximum of the set. You can either write two programs, with 1 program doing each function, or one combined program.

Here's an example in Perl, 50 and 42 bytes (92 total):

Max:

```perl
sub mx {return ( reverse sort {$a <=> $b} @_ )[0]}
```

Min:

```perl
sub mn {return ( sort {$a <=> $b} @_ )[0]}
```

And a single program, 96:

```perl
sub mxmn {return ( reverse sort {$a <=> $b} @_ )[0] if shift; return ( sort {$a <=> $b} @_ )[0]}
```

[Here's some more test cases.](http://pastebin.com/sJ6DjjAK)

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 4310; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to code-golf. Please specify on what kind of input it should run (see [faq](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq) on how to ask questions here). You also have to decide on what you wan't: "simplest way", "code-golf" or "fastest-code"? I suspect they contradict each other.

Comment: @Howard Thanks for telling me. See my post I revised it.

Comment: Your example has holes in it. If passed `( 100, 12 )` it will see 100 as min and 12 as max

Comment: Also, the definition of 'simplest' is highly subjective.

Comment: @Zaid that's weird, I don't see why its doing it

Comment: @linuxrules94 : [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) will sort ASCII-betically by default. That's why 100 comes before 12, since `0 lt 2 == 1`

Comment: -1 because of: 1) language-specific, 2) overly broad (min or max? strings? sweet and simple despite the code-golf tag?); 3) a bit misinformed (Perl *has* min and max)

Comment: @Jb Oh it does never saw that, sorry

Comment: -1 boring. In Golfscript it's `$0=` and `$-1=`.

Comment: It's a one-liner in many languages - not challenging. Prepare your next question in the chat or on meta, where you get hints before going public. I vote to close.

Comment: -1 boring. It's `>./` and `<./` in J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Perl, 28 char

This sub provides an array that contains the min in the first member and the max in the second member:

```
sub a{@_=sort@_;(shift,pop)}
```

### Perl, 34 char (27 inside the sub)

According to comments, in fact the above doesn't work for array length less than 2, here a new attempt that works even for zero length array and array that contains only numerics:

```
sub a{@_&&(sort{$a<=>$b}@_)[0,-1]}
```

Comment: whoa, its 28 char and does min and max and is easy to read? amazing! great job!

Comment: Are you sure that this works e.g. if you provide a single number (and not a list)?

Comment: Make it shorter *and* handle the degenerate case: replace `(shift,pop)` with a slice: `@_[0,-1]`

Comment: And then get rid of temporaries: `sub a{(sort@_)[0,-1]}` is 21 characters long.

Comment: I like this one because you used a language not dedicated to code golf

Comment: Doesn't work. It thinks ten is smaller than two.

Comment: This answer appears to have the same problem as the example in the question. `sort` sorts ASCII-betically (to use Zaid's terminology).  Even though 10 > 2, the first character 1 is less than 2, so 10 get sorted as the smallest number.

Answer (score 1):

Perl does have `min` and `max` subs.

```
use List::Util qw( min max );
my $min = min @values;
my $max = max @values;
```

A common module has a `minmax` function which finds both at once faster than they can be found individually (which is far more important than compactness of code).

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( minmax );
my ($min, $max) = minmax @values;
```

Comment: I only did this as a contest you don't need to use perl but anyway I decided to end it

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be Perl and you just want the simplicity of Scheme instead of just shaving off characters (I don't care about long variable names (symbols in Scheme)), here's my Scheme for this (pun intended):

Of course we could cheat and use the fonctions (min a b c d ...) and (max a b c ...).

Don't mind the long variable names, they were chosen to be descriptive:

```
(define (min . args) (extremum < args))
(define (max . args) (extremum > args))

(define-syntax extremum
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ op . args)
     (if (null? args)
         (error "Read The Fucking Code!")
         (reduce (lambda (a b) (if (op a b) a b))
           (car rest) (cdr rest)))]
    [else (error "Read The Fucking Code!")]))
```

But if you want less code (fold is sort of like reduce):

```
(define (min . args) (e < args)) (define (max . args) (e > args))
(define-syntax e
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ o . r) (fold (lambda (a b) (if (o a b) a b)) (car r) (cdr r))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If all numbers are non-negative, this works:

```
sub max{\@s[@_];$#s}
```

Comment: a.k.a. Thelen's Device. I prefer to write it as `\@_[@_];$#_`, but only because it's more obscure that way.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-g`, 1 byte Min

```
n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P@///2hTHXMdSx1DHTMdEyBtoWOqYxiroJsOAA)

---

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-g`, 2 bytes Max

```
n<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P8/m//9oUx1zHUsdQx0zHRMgbaFjqmMYq6CbDgA)

---

## Total: 3 bytes

Answer (score 1):

Both programs pretty much just evaluate the input & sort it. Min takes the first item of the sorted list, and Max takes the last item of the sorted list.

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 4 bytes Min

```
~$0=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v07FwPb//2hTBXMFSwVDBTMFEyBtoWCqYBgLAA)

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 5 bytes Max

```
~$-1=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05F19D2//9oUwVzBUsFQwUzBRMgbaFgqmAYCwA)

### Total: 9 bytes

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Perl is very golfy for such a problem.

Here are two alternatives for *numerical lists only*:

---

**20 chars (inside sub)**

```
sub min{(sort{$a<=>$b}@_)[0]}
sub max{(sort{$b<=>$a}@_)[0]}
```

---

**30 chars (inside sub)**

```
sub min{$r=pop;$r=$_<$r?$_:$r for@_;$r}
sub max{$r=pop;$r=$_>$r?$_:$r for@_;$r}
```

Comment: Wow amazing only 20 characters! "the greatest thing since sliced bread!" as they would say

Comment: or the greatest thing since [soda] pop (pun intended)

Comment: you may rename the subs to n & x or mx & mn

Comment: or use a different language

Answer (score 0):

## Io, 28 + 28 = 56

I found the magical pure-arithmetic max/min functions! (You guys definitely have a better formula than be, so feel free to mention a better one!)

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 28 bytes

The max function;

```
method(x,y,(x+y+(x-y)abs)/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n5tYoWBlqxDzPze1JCM/RaNCp1JHo0K7UlujQrdSMzGpWFPfSBOkSsNQx0hToaAoM68kJ@8/AA)

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 28 bytes

Min function

```
method(x,y,(x+y-(x-y)abs)/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n5tYoWBlqxDzPze1JCM/RaNCp1JHo0K7UlejQrdSMzGpWFPfSBOkSsNQx0hToaAoM68kJ@8/AA)

### Explanation for both programs

In order to find a purely-arithmetic max-min function, I started to think of averages. Let's take 3 and 4 as examples.

```
(3+4)/2 = 3.5
```

We can see that the distance towards both sides are equal:

```
3 - 3.5 = -0.5
4 - 3.5 = 0.5
```

We do the difference and take the absolute value, to get the distance that we need to add / subtract towards the average. `0.5` in this case.

Then, we find the average again. If we're finding the max, we add it by the distance, otherwise we subtract the value by the distance:

```
3.5 + 0.5 = 4
3.5 - 0.5 = 3
```

Our current expression is:

```
x + y   | x - y     |
----- ± | ----- - x |
  2     |   2       |
```

Actually, the rightmost x can also be y, but we chose x for the simplicity of simplification.

````
x + y   | x - y   2x  |
----- ± | ----- - --- |
  2     |   2      2  |

=

x + y   | x - y - 2x |
----- ± | ---------- |
  2     |     2      |

=

x + y   | x - y |
----- ± ---------
  2         2    

And then, the formula becomes the current formula:

x + y ± | x - y |
-----------------
       2
```
````